# The output from "pandoc -f markdown -t native" shell command differs from the results generated by Pandoc Haskell library

Tags: haskell, markdown, pandoc

Executing the following command

```bash
pandoc -f markdown example.md -t native
```

on

**example.md**

```
$(λx.M)$
```

produces:

```
[ Para [ Math InlineMath "(\955x.M)" ] ]
```

However, the following code reads from that same file:

```hs
module Main where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Catch
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO
import Text.Pandoc

main :: IO ()
main = 
  TIO.putStrLn 
    =<< 
      runIOorExplode (do
        markdownText <- liftIO $ TIO.readFile "example.md"
        doc <- readMarkdown def markdownText
        writeNative def doc
      )
```

and produces:

```hs
[ Para [ Str "$(\955x.M)$" ] ]
```

What's happening here ? Why isn't math blocks being parsed as `Math` types ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandoc allows to enable or disable various extensions for the formats that it supports. The `def` default set of extensions contains only a few extensions that work with most formats. For pandoc's Markdown you'll need [`pandocExtensions`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-3.1.2/docs/Text-Pandoc-Extensions.html#v:pandocExtensions) from the `Text.Pandoc.Extensions` module. Modifying the reader args to use those, and passing the modified options as the first arg to `readMarkdown` should give the desired result.